Primevue FileUpload component custom error messages
I am using template (https://primevue.org/fileupload/#template), and would like to access maxFileSize error from a method in order to show it in a toast component. Is it possible?

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78988977/10030695

If you use the maxFileSize property of the FileUpload component, its internal error handler will automatically be triggered. Unfortunately, there is no hook provided for this. The built-in max-file-size validation triggers an error for the file selection even before the select event is called.
You can bypass this by leaving the maxFileSize value at its default null and writing your own maximum file size checker in the file select event, where you can define custom actions. Remember, in this case, it will be your responsibility to remove the file from the input field (with remove() API function) if it exceeds the allowed size.


const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const fileUploader = ref(null);
    const MY_CUSTOM_MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB
    
    const onSelect = (event) => {
      // Check if the error is due to maxFileSize
      if (MY_CUSTOM_MAX_FILE_SIZE !== null) {
        const { files } = event
        files.forEach((file) => {
          if (file.size > MY_CUSTOM_MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
            // Custom error handling
            const maxSizeMB = (MY_CUSTOM_MAX_FILE_SIZE / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);
            const receivedSizeMB = (file.size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);

            console.error(`Error: File size exceeds the allowed limit. Max size: ${maxSizeMB} MB, Received size: ${receivedSizeMB} MB`);

            // Manually remove from files
            fileUploader.value.remove(file);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    return {
      fileUploader,
      onSelect,
    };
  },
});

app.use(PrimeVue.Config, {
  theme: {
    preset: PrimeVue.Themes.Aura,
  },
});

app.component('p-fileupload', PrimeVue.FileUpload);

app.mount('#app');
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/umd/primevue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@primevue/themes/umd/aura.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p-fileupload
    ref="fileUploader"
    url="/nonexistent-url-error-simulation"
    @select="onSelect"
    :auto="true"
  />
</div>




Select Event - PrimeVue Docs
Remove a file with remove API function - PrimeVue Docs

